# Notification Not trigger in service with Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, notifications

i'm trying to trigger a notification from service using BroadcastReceiver  but it is not triggered, i tried without broadcast receiver , it is triggered so i don't know what is wrong with my broadcast receiver this is a piece of  my code:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

    private NotificationManagerCompat compat;
    private int num;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private IntentFilter intentFilter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        compat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String hometeam = intent.getStringExtra("hometeam");
        String awayteam = intent.getStringExtra("awayteam");
        String date  = intent.getStringExtra("date");
        String time = intent.getStringExtra("time");

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(!time.equals(""))
                {
                    shownotification(date,hometeam,awayteam);
                }

               }

        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
        return START_STICKY;

    }
```

after checking the code deeply the broadcast receiver is the one not working properly , if i comment the broadcast receiver the notification gets triggered

this part of code dosnt work and i don't know why

```
 broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(!time.equals(""))
                {
                    shownotification(date,hometeam,awayteam);
                }

               }

        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
        return START_STICKY;
```

Comment: How does the code look like which "starts" the NotificationService?

Comment: I basically make an intent to open the notificationservice class , and pass some extras like hometeam , awyateam , date , i checked the whole code it is working fine , it dosnt only work in the broadcast receiver part

Comment: Why do you need a BroadcastReceiver? You just want to display a notification when the NotificationService starts, right?

Comment: what i want to acheive is when the app is not running( not in background or foreground , when the app is not at all opened ) , i would still be able to send notification to the user